# Isolate values based on format in mysql

Tags: mysql, formatting

I have a date column that is really messed up.

It had %m/%d/%y values that I have reformatted to %Y-%m-%d like they should be.

Now I am discovering that there are records that have a date in them that are %d%y%m!!

Now I need to only select those values that look like 000000 and nothing that is 0000-00-00 or 0000/00/00.

What is the best way to isolate that format?

Thanks

Comment: select * where col LIKE '_____'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the date column types to avoid such issues. This also allows you to use the [mysql date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

To solve your issue you can use `select * from mytable where mydate not like '____-%__%__' and not like '____/__/__'` (note the number of underscores).

If this is not enough for you, use a mysql [regular expression](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/regexp.html).